# how to handle api from Teamcity server itself after build is triggered for SVN

Tags: api, teamcity, mediawiki, hsqldb

I have configured a SVN file in TeamCity server. And also set the property "Trigger a build on each check-in". So the file Build is triggered after every check-in is happened. Now I want to access the build information of configured SVN files while build is triggering.

I have a web space in Mediawiki. Mediawiki has some api to edit/create pages. I wish to call Mediawiki api with SVN build information from TeamCity server itself.

Is there any way to do this ?

what is the HSQL2 database in Teamcity server. Can we use this DB to access build information ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TeamCity REST API to get the build changes, example:

```
curl /httpAuth/app/rest/changes?build=id:%teamcity.build.id%
```

As a command line build step will yield something like:

```
<changes count="3">
   <change href="/httpAuth/app/rest/changes/id:217404" id="217404" version="b6b97a0d7789d97df6df908ab582ebb723235f43" webLink="http://teamcity.my-domain.com/viewModification.html?modId=217404&personal=false"/>
   <change href="/httpAuth/app/rest/changes/id:217403" id="217403" version="064ecef5552ec2fb7875d7c26fe54cdf94b67bec" webLink="http://teamcity.my-domain.com/viewModification.html?modId=217403&personal=false"/>
   <change href="/httpAuth/app/rest/changes/id:217402" id="217402" version="9bc3a34c952059bbfc7bebeb79ba5a3c894ef555" webLink="http://teamcity.my-domain.com/viewModification.html?modId=217402&personal=false"/>
</changes>
```

Then you can loop through the change and hit its `href` which will yield like:

```
<change date="20130918T133404-0600" username="welsh" href="/httpAuth/app/rest/changes/id:217397" id="217397" version="51e925e354a83deccde881b30a76974b2ff745f4" webLink="http://teamcity.my-domain.com/viewModification.html?modId=217397&personal=false">
  <comment>
My comments are here
  </comment>
  <files>
    <file before-revision="90acd4da1972814094c22e3020c5073521a7b640@141323126c0" after-revision="51e925e354a83deccde881b30a76974b2ff745f4@1413290abe0" file="grails-app/views/layouts/global.gsp" relative-file="grails-app/views/layouts/global.gsp"/>
  </files>
  <user href="/httpAuth/app/rest/users/id:1" id="1" name="Welsh" username="welsh"/>
</change>
```

Then you can create something to take this information to push it to your media wiki.

Comment: Hi Welsh, I Installed the cURL and tried with custom script in command line for new build step.                                                             curl -v --basic --user admin:admin http://localhost:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/changes?build=id:%teamcity.build.id%.                                                                       But it shows error while build run. 
Build errors
[16:22:01]Step 2/2: Command Line.
[16:22:01][Step 2/2] Step Command Line failed.

Comment: That error isn't the actual error. You'll need to look at the build log to see why the cURL command failed. I suggest getting it working on your local using a build that has already finished then moving to getting it working as a build step.

Comment: Yes Welsh, It was working. I made a mistake in the command line. Now its working.

Comment: Hi Welsh, In your above answer you mentioned command line will yield something like HTML info. I tried with the curl command line. It brings the current build id and TCSSESSIONID in build log. Also you mentioned we can loop through the href. But I cannot see the href from result. 

How can we done the loop in script for build log ?

How do we create a command line curl OR Powelshell script to access the build info dynamically in Teamcity ?

Comment: It returns XML and you'll need to use something probably like Python/Ruby/Perl/Java that could access the REST Service and then extract the href list and perform additional calls. You also won't see hrefs in the build if there are no changes that are present in the build. But `%teamcity.build.id%` will return the current build ID of the running build which you can use to get list of changes.